# RightToLeft flag and atomic group

Tags: c#, regex

Why `a(?>.*)` does not match `abc` when RightToLeft is activated?

The way I expected it to work is:

1. The right-most character (`c`) does not match the `a`.
2. The next character is `b`. It again won't match `a`.
3. `a` matches `a`; the greedy `.` inside the atomic group will match b and c. There are no more characters and the regex is satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't really related to the RightToLeft option. The string is searched in a reverse order, but other thing that needs to be taken in account is that the pattern tokens are tested in the reverse order too. So `(?>.*)` first, and then `a`.

An atomic group forbids backtracking. Since `.*` is by default greedy, it takes c, then b, then a (in other words it takes "abc"), but because of the atomic group `.*` will not give a character back (the a) and the pattern will fail.

*(Note that without the RightToLeft option you are in the same situation in which you try to find occurrences in "cba" with the pattern `(?>.*)a`)*

A more simple example without the RightToLeft option, always with the string "abc" but with the pattern `a(?>.*)c`:

```
a         =>   a
a(?>.*)   =>   abc
a(?>.*)c  =>   FAIL since (?>.*) don't give back the c
```

If this time I use a non-capturing group instead of an atomic group: `a(?:.*)c`

```
a         =>   a
a(?:.*)   =>   abc
a(?:.*)c  =>   FAIL
a(?:.*)   =>   ab (Backtracking)
a(?:.*)c  =>   abc (Succeed)
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I think that the sentence "it does not interpret the regular expression pattern from right to left." from the doc only means that the pattern is not seen like `)*.>?(a`, but to search from right to left, I assume that tokens are tested from right to left too, so `(?>.*)` first, and `a` after.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly the sentence that misled me. After reading this answer and then testing `(?<a>.*)?(?<b>.*)?` over `xyz` in both RightToLeft and non-RightToLeft modes it became clear to me that the flag does actually affect how the pattern is interpreted and not just the direction of the search through the target string.

Comment: @AXO: this sentence is indeed unclear, we don't know what to think. I think that this option is designed for languages written from right to left, so testing tokens in a reverse order is a logical choice (it's more easy to search a word with its beginning than to search a word with its end that is potentially common to many other words. But I'm not linguist, it's only an assumption).